Build distribution package for different platform architecture
We have Jenkins pipeline that runs on X86 architecture and invokes following command:
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

I would like to build a package for ARM-based architecture. Is it possible by adding some additional configuration to setup.py?

Sure thing:
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --plat-name=manylinux2014_aarch64

See documentation for more options.
